# MongoDB and PyMongo - SQL like columns

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MySQL database with a table called ***sources***, there I have two columns called ***srctype*** and ***url*** where srctype is a name (e.g: Hello) and url is an url (e.g: http://google.com)

In Python using SQLAlchemy, I could filter the srctype and get a list of the urls, for example;

```
src = "hello"    
links = session.query(sources).filter_by(srctype=src).all()
```

Easy, now I am migrating this data to a MongoDB, for this I am using ***pymongo***.

I have a function where it saves the srctype and url to mongodb's database

```
    def insertSources(self, srctype, link):
        """ Insert rss sources so we can parse them """
        new = {srctype: link}
        self.__sources.insert(new)
```

and a function that retrieves the srctype

```
 def getSources(self, type=None, single=True): # type == srctype
    if type:
        if single:
            return self.__sources.find_one()
        else:
            return iter(self.__sources.find({srctype:type}))
    else:
        if single:
            return self.__sources.find_one()
        else:
            return iter(self.__sources.find())
```

The problem here is, since there is no column called srctype and no column called url, how can I do the same as the SQLAlchemy/MySQL example?

In MySQL would be;

```
SELECT * FROM sources WHERE srctype="hello"
```

I wonder how will that be in the retrieve function I have (also in the insert function, since I am not sure if what I did there is correct for the job I want). In the *insertSources* function I simple add a *dict* to MongoDB, clearly I won't be able to get the srctype in the getSources function, since srctype in MongoDB is no column. 
Any help would be great.

Comment: Why would you want to migrate data that you want to access in an SQL-like manner to a NoSQL database? Is this just an exercise to work with Mongo?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is a real job where I was asked to do this, but then I got hooked up with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not setting the name correctly when saving the data. Instead of

```
def insertSources(self, srctype, link):
    """ Insert rss sources so we can parse them """
    new = {srctype: link}
    self.__sources.insert(new)
```

You should do

```
def insertSources(self, srctype, link):
    """ Insert rss sources so we can parse them """
    new = {'srctype': srctype, 'link': link}
    self.__sources.insert(new)
```

And similarly in `getSources()`. If `srctype` is passed, `find()` and `find_one()` should receive `{'srctype': type}`.

Comment: This is indeed what I thought before, but the each site has a different srctype, that's why the SQL example, column -> srctype -> different names; column url -> different links -> fetch the whole row

Comment: Did the fix, but I wonder, is this a "quick" fix? Is there such a thing like "columns" in MongoDB? Or your example is the way? Cheers!

Comment: I think you need to stop thinking of columns, and start thinking of keys. MongoDB essentially uses dictionaries instead of named tuples.